# What is the best way to handle two separate ajaxes in laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

So i have a page with two separate ajax call ( with laravel ) , when first one is executed then the second one has to run but second ajax's options is in selectbox. here is my solution ( with bad heart ofcourse) :

```
 public function getCategoryAjax(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::where('category_id',$request->get('category_id'))->get();

    return $product;
}
public function getPriceAjax(Request $request)
{
    $withPrice = Product::where('category_id',$request->get('category_id'));
    if ($request->get('price') == 1){
        $withPrice=$withPrice->where('min_price','<', 1000000)->get();
    }elseif ($request->get('price') == 2){
        $withPrice=$withPrice->where('min_price','>', 1000000)->andWhere('max_price','<',2000000)->get();
    }


    return $withPrice;
}
```

first method is for first ajax , in the second one  i'm doing if elseif for handling options in selectbox

So here is my question , is there a better way to do this?
[image]
(the select box in the left is for second ajax

Comment: What is your problem? Any errors? Just define 2 routes & 2 actions in the view.

Comment: @timod just said it... it's not a problem it's about performance and code style and standards

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about better way to handling multiple if conditions in **getPriceAjax(Request $request)** function...

If this is your problem  you can write your code like this...

```
// Set all your min-max price rules in array, by this you can easily modilfy every price option rule..
protected $priceRules = array(
    1 => ["0", "1000000"],
    2 => ["1000000", "2000000"],
    3 => ["2000000", "3000000"],
    4 => ["3000000", "4000000"],
    // ... so on
);

public function getPriceAjax(Request $request) {
    $price = $request->get('price');
    // check given option is in array or not... some validation..
    if (isset($this->priceRules[$price])) {
        // It will dynamically handle all your price option query...
        $withPrice = Product::where('category_id', $request->get('category_id'))->whereBetween('price', $this->priceRules[$price])->get();
        return $withPrice;
    }
    return 'error';

}
```

Hope it helps you...